# Find the upper bound for $\chi(G)$ using theorem 8.20

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given following graph 
[image]

a) Find the upper bound for $\chi(G)$ using theorem 8.20

b)What is $\chi(G)$?

> **Theorem 8.20**: For every graph $G$, $\chi(G) \leq 1+\max\{\delta(H)\}$, where maximum is taken over all subgraph $H$ of $G$

I know that $\chi(G)=5$ so part b) is done. For part a), I'm not quite sure about $\max\{\delta(H)\}$ part, so I need to find the minimum degree in all subgraph $H$ and pick the biggest one? Is $\max\{\delta(H)\}=5$? Do I need to prove it?

Comment: Ah, good old Theorem 8.20. A valiant effort. But not a patch on 7.20, but there you are. Seriously, you should make your posts as readable as possible, defining where necessary notation that isn't universal.

Comment: The notation $\delta(H)$ should be the maximum degree of $H$, I believe. And note that it is not necessary to take the maximum of all the $\delta(H)$, since if $H$ is a subgraph of $H'$ then $\delta(H)\leq \delta(H')$. Therefore the bound should be $\chi(G)\leq 1+\delta(G)$.

Comment: @zarathustra $\delta(H)$ is the minimum degree, $\Delta(H)$ is the max degree

Comment: Yes, in order to use goold old Thm 8.20, you need to prove that $M = max\{\delta(H)\} = 5$.  Not too hard in this case, as $G$ is 5-regular.  This shows that $M \geq 5$, and $M \leq 5$ is obvious since no vertex has degree bigger than 5.  This gives you $\chi(G) \leq 6$.  However, finding the exact value for $\chi(G)$ is another story.

Comment: Ok, then in order to prove $\max_H \delta(H)=5$ you can use the fact that $G$ is $5$-regular.

Comment: How is $G$ 5-regular? I see vertices of degree 3 and 4 as well. But if you remove the vertex of degree 3, the remaining graph has minimum degree 4, which gives you the desired upper bound.

Comment: @Leen I see no vertices of degree 3 or 4.  I only see vertices of degree 5 and 6.  The degree of a vertex is the number of edges (with loops counted twice) touching the vertex.  The entire outside pentagon (as pictured) has degree 5, the top middle also has degree 5, the two below that though are each of degree 6.  Ergo, $\delta(G)=5$.  Taking $H=G$ you see that $\max_H \delta(H)\geq 5$, and with a bit more convincing you see that you cannot have an $H$ with $\delta(H)=6$ (since there are strictly fewer than 6 vertices with $\deg_G (v) \geq 6$).

Comment: @JMoravitz Are we looking at the same picture? The outside pentagon has (for my eyes) 2 vertices of degree 4 and 3 of degree 5. The top center vertex has degree 3. I see no loops at all.

Comment: @JMoravitz We have a different definition of "top center vertex". For me it is the topmost vertex of the three vertices inside the cycle. I have refreshed the page, use a high resolution and it still has degree 3.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I see the two bent edges and the edge to the top of the 5-cycle. No others. I give up, let's wait what Diane has to say.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have set the picture as my wallpaper and now I see the extra edges. The entire horizontal line disappears in the browser display. Sorry. It is still not 5-regular, but now the exceptional vertices at least have higher degree.

Comment: Weird stuff going on here - it's kind of funny.  I couldn't see the degree 6 vertices, until I did just as @Leen did - I had to set the picture as my wallpaper to see a missing edge!

Comment: It must be some strange rendering issue. All lines in the pictures in the answer are equally clear, but in the question picture they are all very different. The line @Manuel is missing is for me the 'best', i.e. thickest line in the picture, the bottom horizontal line is hardly visible. The non-horizontal lines have gaps in them.

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the website, or the way I upload the picture. I'm not sure how it appear in your screen, it seem like some edges just mixed together? The picture in the answer is exactly what I was trying to draw

Comment: I also has one more question , when I have $\delta(G)=x$ and $\Delta(G)=y$ such that $y-x=1$. Is it safe to say that $max \{ \delta(H)\}=\delta (G)$ ?

Comment: Well, $G$ could be a disjoint union of a clique of size $x + 1$ and a clique of size $y + 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see , thanks Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146822/find-the-upper-bound-for-chig-using-theorem-8-20#comment2340248_1146822) points out, there are only two vertices of degree at least six, so $\max_{H \subseteq G} \delta(H) \leq 5$. By deleting the edge that connects these two vertices of degree six, we obtain a $5$-regular subgraph $H'$ so that $\max_{H \subseteq G} \delta(H) \geq \delta(H') = 5$. Hence, using the given theorem, it follows that:
$$
\chi(G) \leq 1 + \max_{H \subseteq G} \delta(H)
= 1 + 5
= 6
$$
Now to obtain the lower bound $\chi(G) \geq 5$, we argue by contradiction. Suppose instead that $G$ is $4$-colourable. Then without loss of generality, we can colour the four vertices of the $4$-clique subgraph with four distinct colours as follows:

[image]

But by symmetry, $G$ has another $4$-clique, two of which are coloured blue and purple. This forces the remaining two vertices of this reflected $4$-clique to be coloured as follows:

[image]

But it is now impossible to properly colour the topmost vertex, as it is adjacent to four vertices with four different colours. To prove the tighter upper bound $\chi(G) \leq 5$, we use the following proper $5$-colouring:

[image]

Thus, $\chi(G) = 5$, as desired.